# Adding dll to spring mvc project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, java-7, m2eclipse

I have a spring mvc project using Eclipse Kepler and want to use a .net dll in that project.

I went through the process of getting the dll ready for java following [this info](http://codefry.blogspot.com/2012/01/calling-net-dlls-from-java-code-without.html)

In my

```
spring project -> Properties -> Java Class Path -> libraries -> External Jar -> Located my jar used to call the c# methods.
```

Next added the native libs

```
spring project -> Properties -> Java Class Path -> libraries -> Located external jar added -> expand -> highlight Native Library Locaton -> path to where my dll's are located
```

In my spring mvc project code I can create an instance of the object in my external jar file.

```
MyJavaCallingComObject testObj = new MyJavaCallingComObject ();
testObj.GetDetails("John Doe");

GetDetails = supposed to return user information given the user name
```

However when i go to call a method I run into this

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (os_windows_x86.cpp:143), pid=8644, tid=10476
#  guarantee(result == EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION) failed: Unexpected result from topLevelExceptionFilter
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

My Eclipse is located on `c:\eclipse`

All my work spaces are located on `d:\workspaces`

Answer (score 1):

I guess this article described exactly what you are looking for:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/building-java-applications-use

It's showing step by step guide for building Sprint MVC application that leverages the .NET DLLs used directly from JAVA.